# Supporting the Filipino language

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

I am trying to support filipino in my android app. But when I create a folder named raw-fil, I see a compiler error that the resource folder name is not valid.

Comment: rename the folder to raw_fil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Nothing seems to work. Neither `raw-ph`, `raw-rPH` or `raw-fil`. I am going ahead with custom handling by using:

```
Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fil"){
    //load resources from another location
}
```

Comment: Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("fil")  == 'values-tl' as a resource directory. I had hard time to find the right one tho. I actually searched for phillippines flag in Intellij Translation Edtitor :) @strange-coroner answer is right

Answer (score 7):

[There is no ISO 639-1 code for Flipino](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php). Hence, I am not aware that you can write an app that offers Filipino translations, as Android uses ISO 639-1, not ISO 639-2 (where `fil` would be valid).

Answer (score 4):

Try `raw-tl` (Tagalog is the filipino language).

Answer (score 1):

For Android Studio, try using this. create another values folder named

> **values-tl-rPH**

place your **strings.xml** that contains your Filipino strings inside this folder.

now to make your app use those strings. change your app locale by using 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10596034/5285687)
consider also seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24908330/5285687)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can support Filipino or Tagalog as languages, but you can support the Philippines as a region using `raw-rPH`.

Answer (score 0):

For Android studio, I used values-tl for the values folder and it works for Tagalog.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder name with Values-fil. For Further information
You can look at this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en)