# i am trying to make android app which will contain story[Textual]

Tags: android, database, android-database

I am thinking to make book like app which should have more then 100 topic to read. And user can even change language like Hindi or English  . Basically it will behave as book. My question is that where should I store that textual data in XML file or in database . If answer is database then how can I change language of textual data in app

Comment: Store it in a file and read only the next 5-10 page of the book at the time.

Comment: then how will i change language ?

Comment: Man, you can detect lacale changes...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by android book.
Anyway if you are asking about how to change the language of your app maybe this link is what do you need:

[How can I change language of my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464771/how-can-i-change-language-of-my-application)

Comment: i want to make app which will contain lots of textual data like story , so where i should store that textual data in xml or in database . if data base then how can i change language to hindi or other language

Comment: i know how to change language . but in that case data are in xml . So can i store my whole textual data in string.xml file ?

Comment: I'll probably go for something different; if you are thinking to do an app with a lot of textual data you can choice ether xml or sql... it will be a mess.
How about simply store everything in a json file?
In that case you have only to correctly change the file to read according to the language and it will be a lot more easy to deal with.