# How to change android app language without changing phone language?

Tags: android, localization

I want user to select a language inside the app. Once the language is selected, I want the strings to use the particular language.

If I change the phone language, then my app runs on the set language.

I am not able to find any way to set a language without changing the phone language. In addition, the changes should be reflected once the language is set.

Could anyone please suggest a way to do it?

Comment: Kindly use localisation in app

Comment: @JhamanDas actually I am a newbie to localization. Could you please share resource guide, link or something?

Comment: yes sure, make strings file like fi u want to use arabic language create values-ar folder and created strings resource file

Comment: Try to read this first. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12954037/4198633 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596034/4198633. This should do the trick...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void changeLang(Context context, String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Lang parameter should be "en" for English, "it" for Italian... After that you should restart your activity/fragment

Comment: What's the best way to restart the activity? And how can I implement this into settings?

Comment: @Avi, just simply called `recreate()` in Activity after changing the language.

Comment: Without recreating activity or fragment is it possible?@aloj, @Sam

Comment: @MaulikDodia yes, it is possible. aloj code does work!

Comment: @Sam I tried aloj's code but it doesn't work without **recreating / refreshing** activity.

Comment: @MaulikDodia It is really hard to help without the sample code of what you have done (especially your logic). But I can tell you, aloj answer above does work. I am also quite **new** with Android. Perhaps aloj can help?

Comment: @Sam My StackOverflow question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020167/changing-the-app-language-run-time-without-recreating-the-activity). If you get time kindly look into it.

Comment: The solution just work in the current activity, if you back to the previous activity it doesn't work any more.

Comment: @Sam "just simply called recreate() in Activity after changing the language" and how do you know this when the user goes to their settings and changes language? Not just something happens within the controlled environment of your app?