# How to change Locale without re-launching application?

Tags: android, android-activity

Basically what I am trying to do is,

I start with `MainActivity(activity_main)` go to `SettingActivity(activity_setting)` & change my locale from given options(like french, english, dutch etc.)

So what I have done till now is...

`OnClick` of language name it re-create `SettingActivity(activity-setting)` & change it's `string` values according to language selected.

What I really want is Without re-creating Activity, All `string` values should be applied according to that selected language.

All suggestions & Answers are greatly appreciated.
Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Related: [How to change android app language without changing phone language?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942736/how-to-change-android-app-language-without-changing-phone-language)

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the language property first.
Then call a new function that sets all strings displayed in the UI to the right language.

Pseudocode:

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewbyId(R.id.tv1);
myTextView.setText(yourCustomGetLocaleFunction("some id of the string you want to display", "some language name"));
```

But that's a bad approach. You should let Android handle the language of your app. Just localize the strings.xml file (you can load strings from the file from code).

Edit:

To change the language of your app for the moment, you can use the Code from this solution:
[How to change android app language without changing phone language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39942736/how-to-change-android-app-language-without-changing-phone-language)