# How to increase the accuracy of the Speech to Text converter

Tags: android, performance, speech-to-text

I am using speech-to-text conversion in my application, based on Android API's. It is working pretty well ... but currently it is utilizing US accent as a basis. This results in the application sometimes matching words entirely different from what I said. I want to improve the performance of my application. Can anybody help me???

Can anybody tell me that how to emulate a certain accent in my aaplication?

Answer (score 0):

It can only be improved if the existing software has the facility to train. Or else you need to emulate a certain accent.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the locale on the emulator.

To do so programatically:
[Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)

Otherwise, in the emulator, just go to settings:
menu -> settings -> language and keyboard -> select language

Comment: I dnt knw how to do this... :(