# Localization in Android without depending on the device language

Tags: android

Is it possible to create a localized android application independent from the device's language. For example in .net we set `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` to the specified language, is this possible in android? The goal is to create a multilingual android application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself/2271141#2271141)

Additional Tips:

To get the current Language :

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

To get the current Locale

```
String locale = context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayName();
```

or

```
String locale = java.util.Locale.getDefault().getDisplayName();
```

Read this article on [Localization strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: Thanks, but what I actually want is not to get the locale, I need to change it and only for my application, not the whole device

Comment: Oh in that case, [refer to this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself/2271141#2271141)

Comment: Thanks, it worked great, with your permission I will update your answer to set it as accepted answer, Regards