# onConfigurationchanged is not called over jellybean(4.2.1)

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I really suffer from this issue.
I already set the flag `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale"`

But when I changed configuration of language, `onconfigurationchanged` function isn't called.
The strange thing is that my codes work fine over other android platform.

I searched this issue here.
Someone said that I need to set `sdk` version lower. But it didn't work.

Please give me some tips.

Answer (score 14):

Add the `layoutDirection` attribute, such as `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|locale|layoutDirection"` if you're working with API 17.

`layoutDirection` that is also connected with interface language changes was introduced in API 17. [Piece of android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) about `android:configChanges` is not explicit enough about that fact, but at least we have:

> **layoutDirection:** The layout direction has changed. For example, changing from
>   left-to-right (LTR) to right-to-left (RTL). **Added in API level 17**.

Comment: Thank so much. :) Your answer is working. Why should i add layoutDirection configuration for checking whether locale is changed or not?? it is so strange.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! But, what is the link between layoutDirection and locale?!?

Comment: The link between layoutDirection and locale is support for right-to-left languages.

Answer (score 6):

From Android 4.2, layout direction will be updated when we change language.
Then we have to add both "locale" and "layoutDirection" as below
android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection",
that time onConfigurationChanged() will be called.

This is similar with "orientation" and "screenSize" in API 13.

Answer (score -13):

do u config AndroidManifest.xml like this?

> android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="17"

you need to remove android:targetSdkVersion attribute