# Android: On 4.2 Jellybean "android:configChanges" not working for locale change

Tags: android

I have designed the app for handling the Locale change during the app life cycle.
The entry in `manifest` `android:configChanges="locale"` works well & call the `onConfigurationChanged` in activity, which handles the locale related code.

But the same logic not working for 4.2 `JellyBean` devices.

The activity `onDestroy` is called instead of `onConfigurationChanged` when `locale` is changed.

Is this something specific to 4.2 & how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Can you add some sample code? I'd be interested to see how you change the locale with android 4.1. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Android has filtered out the CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission on 4.2 for some reason.

You can read more here: [Android 4.2 filters out CHANGE_CONFIGURATION permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13440045/android-4-2-filters-out-change-configuration-permission)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer here: [onConfigurationchanged is not called over jellybean(4.2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856229/onconfigurationchanged-is-not-called-over-jellybean4-2-1)

You need to add `layoutDirection` attribute,  example code below:

```
android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"
```