# Changing the language in fragment is destroying the view

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `MainActivity` wherein I am inserting a fragment over it.

In fragment there is `EditText`, `Button` ,`TextView` , `ImageView`.
When i enter some text in `EditText` it shows the same in `TextView`. And when i click on profile-image default Icon(Image View) it asks us to upload image from sd card and sets that as Profile Image.

Before clicking on submit button if i go to settings and change the language to say Japanese then after coming back to my app does not refresh the same using Japanese text. And even image uploaded but not saved also disappears. 
I have `values-ja` for the Japanese script.

I read about `onConfigChanges` method in `Activity`. I tried that also but that method is also not getting called.

Comment: Use Fragment as Alias activity , and then use android:config changes in Manifest

Comment: I dint get what you trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read those article, then you can solve your problem

[How to refresh activity after changing language (Locale) inside application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application)

[Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)