# Change Language of Application at time of Programming

Tags: android

In my app,i have used 'locale' to change language hindi in programatically.and i also used  .ttf file to convert title of app sub page in hindi language.but when i change language ,the other control change language automatically..for ex,datepicker etc,

when i have to set value in textview directly,its value can't be converted in hindi .but when i have some changes regarding that value and after set value in textview,then it will convert hindi language automaetically.please give me some solution of this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application?rq=1)

Comment: yes..i already check this link..but i have to build my app as 4.0.1 (min version)and android:configChanges="locale"  use 4.2 and above api support.so plese give me some other solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you from my own experiences that it will result in strange behaviour when changing the language "manually". It is not recommended. Sometimes even changing the device orientation will overwrite your changes due to the changed configuration. Just be aware that this approach is not supported or intended by Android.

Comment: but i have to solution of this problem..because this is client requirement..and i can not change my api version.please give me another solution...