# Automatically refresh All view in layout after language change

Tags: android

In my app i have a spinner to select language "en" or "ar".I have `String.xml` for both languages. 
Once we select language from spinner i want my layout to change in language chosen.

I tried this but doesn't change when i select from spinner:

```
 Spinner languageSpinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.languagespinner);
            languageSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                if(arg2==0)
                    languageToLoad  = "en"; // your language
                else
                    languageToLoad  = "ar";
                Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);  
                Locale.setDefault(locale); 
                Configuration config = new Configuration(); 
                config.locale = locale; 
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,  
                getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                onConfigurationChanged(config);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

How can i do it?

Comment: You need to restart your applicaton

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application

Comment: @Mario does Liem Vo answer help you? Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

After setting locale you need to reload your current activity

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

will reload your activity.

Comment: Since i have used spinner everytime i do this it infinitely finishes and restarts my activity

Answer (score 0):

in your activity call this function to restart your activity

```
private void restartActivity() {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of API level >11 you can use

```
recreate()
```

To recreate(new instance) your activity.
Have a look at the [documentation.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#recreate())