# All steps to add "Change language" to Android Preferences

Tags: java, android, xml, android-preferences

I've seen many post, but they just mention the part [how to change the language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183732/changing-language-in-run-time-with-preferences-android) from the activities, but not where they have located the language in their android project. Also in the [official Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html?hl=es-419) it it said to create a new directory, e.i. "values-es", but I just want to change the language (string.xml), not all the other XML I have located inside the "value" directory (colors.xml, styles.xml, etc).

So, what changes should I made to my android project in order to add new "string.xml" files with different languages? Do I have to do as said in the Android developers guide and create a new "values" folder even that means repeat common XML files? This sounds to me like isn't what I need, that can be acomplished with an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really have to copy nothing except `strings.xml`. This should work just fine:

```
- res
    - ...
    - values
        - styles.xml
        - colors.xml
        - dimens.xml
        - strings.xml
        - ...
    - values-es
        - strings.xml
```