# I want to change my application language using shared preference

Tags: android

Here is what I mean when I ask about Setting language using preference. I am using Preference Fragment binding method to bind preference key values to onCreate method. I am getting difficulty in accessing the list preference to change my app language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing language in run time with Preferences \[android\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183732/changing-language-in-run-time-with-preferences-android)

Answer (score -1):

See [Support Diffrent Language Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)

Use Google Translate service to translate the strings into other languages. But if you want more accurate and meaningful translation always go for professional services like Professional translations through Google Play [Localization checklist](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/localization-checklist#gp-trans)

Finally Localization Checklist gives you list of things to be verified before the app goes live when localization considered.