# OnConfigurationChanged is not called after locale config change

Tags: java, android, configuration, locale

What I want to do is to provide a simple language change for the user within the app. The text of the current view as well as the Back Stack should be replaced with the strings of the selected language. I have just written the following code snippet which does his job fine:

```
private void setLocale(Locale locale) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

After some researching I figured out, that every activity should automatically refreshes itself after the locale configuration has been changed - but it doesn't in my case. The current view as well as the whole Back Stack have still the default locale - they just change after reopening the activity.

I have already added the attribute `android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection"` to my `AndroidManifest.xml` so that won't do the trick.

Do you guys have any suggestions? Or do I have the wrong purpose for solving this problem eitherway?

**EDIT**
Okay it seems like `OnConfigurationChanged()` only triggers by changing the language device-wide in the android settings?
Is there any other way to refresh EVERY active activity (current and back stack) after changing the language in my app?

Comment: try after removing "locale" from here android:configChanges="locale|layoutDirection", it will work.

Comment: I'm afraid, but removing "locale" from the AndroidManifest activity attribute didn't work for me to solve this problem. @LoveGrag

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think if you create a Receiver who has this event filter

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCALE_CHANGED"/>`
will give you an event when device locale is changed then you can refresh all activity you want. For refreshing you can look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application).
Hope it will solve your issue.