# How to restart the app when user is in secound actvity and changed language in android

Tags: android, application-restart

I have 2 activities Activity1,Activity2 , when i open my application Activity1 will get displayed from there i will navigate to Activity2 and this time Activity1 is in background.

When i am in Activity2 ,i am Activity2 i am opening the settings and changing the language, then system reload the Activity2 . At this point in time i don't want to display activity2 ,i want to restart my application from starting.

Currently i have tried below logic in fragments which i have used in Activity2 to eliminate the crash.

Fragments:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.point_selection_list_fragment, container, false);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        Utils.removeFragment(this);
        return view;
    }
return view;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refresh activity after changing language (Locale) inside application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049207/how-to-refresh-activity-after-changing-language-locale-inside-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help.

```
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Only problem with this it will not restart the application, only re-create the classes. Thus, any static variables within the classes will retain values from previous runs

Comment: Yes agree with this.

along with this i am doing below.

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(null);
  handleLocalizationChanges(savedInstanceState);

Comment: Ignore above .

Below solved my problem.

     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(null);
 Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
//Make sure to dismiss the alert dialogs if any 
}

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.
finish() both the activities after settings is change and start firstactivity intent.
Thank you
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

See [this solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473168/clear-the-entire-history-stack-and-start-a-new-activity-on-android#5344635) this may help you