# How to display Text in Different languages in a single list view [Android]

Tags: android

I need to display language selection Activity where I want to display List of supported Languages.

I want to display List of languages in the specific language either, English in English, French in French and Japanese in Japanese in one `ListView`.

I know how we can create multy language Application, using different `strings.xml` files.
But don't have any idea, on how to display `ListView` in multiple languages.

Thanks.

Comment: by the way , you are taking strings for your list from strings.xml?

Comment: yes i am taking it from strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all the listview strings in String.xml file Like

```
<string-array name="language_list">
<item>English</item>
<item>Française</item>
<item>日本語</item>
<item>Deutsch</item>
<item>Español</item>
<item>Português</item>
<item>Italiano</item>
<item>简体中国</item>
</string-array>
```

and then populate the array in your java file. using adapter display list for this array.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that Android restricts you to use a specific language for a specific locale. You can define a language list in `values/strings.xml`, fill the `ListView` and change application locale accordingly (see this question: [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/android-changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)).