# How do I access default locale resource strings in Android whilst in a different locale?

Tags: android, resources, locale

If I switch my phone's locale to German for example, I still want the option to be able to access the english / default resources using something along the lines of:

```
getString(R.string.some_text, locale);
```

I've tried switching the default locale using

```
Locale.setDefault
```

but as expected, when using R.getString(x), my resource was still in German.

Answer:

[Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)