# Android: Regarding using different strings based on user choice

Tags: android, string

You can use strings in this way: `" R.string.*"` or in xml: `"android:text=@strings/*"` - right?

They all take their values out of a fixed file named strings where you put them all in right?

Let's say I have an app where there is the possibility to change language. Is there a way in which I can change that string file? Let's say have a strings file for English and strings for  French or anything.. so i can still use the `R.string.*` and `@string/*` but I will get different values depends on the user choice?

Comment: I believe you're talking about localization. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Developer's Guide on [Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html#creating-alternatives) covers this.

In short use the same string names, but have different locale folders, like:

- `res/values/strings.xml` for the default language
- `res/values-fr/strings.xml` for French
- `res/values-ja/strings.xml` for Japanese

The OS will load the appropriate language for `R.string.hello` for you.

Comment: Yes, Exactly what I was talking about

Comment: You can also change the locale from user input to offer language support. Say the user selects French from a preference setting in your app, now no matter what Locale the device is actually in it will display the French strings with: [Changing Locale within the app itself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4239680/1267661).

Comment: Thank you sam again, but i already found out about it by myself, This is what i was looking for... Yet again I am surprised how easy it is to develop for android :D