# Multi language Android application

Tags: android, configuration, localization, multilingual

I'm creating a multi language android application and I made folders with different languages and everything works perfect.

The only issue that troubles me is when user selects a different language I use a method to change his local configuration and this is also working great! **BUT** I don't feel that changing the user local setting is the right way because changing the local setting effecting not just my application.

Is there smarter way? I don't want the to affect the user setting outside my application.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, other solutions that provide the user with the ability to change the language from within the app are hard to implement and full of hacks. Lets say Android is built this way.

Comment: myself as a user dont want any application to change my local setting...and i dont think i"m alone on this

Comment: you can go the hard way but don't recommend it, if your native language is English why would you want the app to be in French while the os is in English?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself

Comment: simple , my native is not english but from the day i touched computer i know that everything works better with english unless the program\application is made especially for my native language .