# Android loading resources for Simplified/traditional Chinese

Tags: android, localization, resources, locale

I am creating an android app which manually setting the user's locale within the app

```
Locale loc = new Locale(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE.getLanguage());
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = loc;
...
```

I want the app to load automatically different string.xml based on settings
When I set the locale to Traditional Chinese it worked fine to load the string.xml in "res/values-zh" 
But when I create a res folder for simplified chinese ("res/values-cn" or "res/values-zh-rCN") it just cant load it correctly (still loaded traditional chinese)

Code:

```
loc = new Locale(Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE.getLanguage());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're not actually changing the app's Locale configuration.   Android seems like it's still using the default locale.

see [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)