# Chinese locale values-zh_CN gives an error on Eclipse

Tags: android, localization

I've created a `values-zh_CN` directory in my `res` folder for Simplified Chinese localization. Eclipse does not accept that folder name, it marks it as an error, the directory itself.

The problem is definitely with the directory name, if I change the directory name to `values-nl` for example the error comes off.

The only name Eclipse accepts is `values-zh-rCN` which compiles fine but the actual locale is not loaded (Default en is loaded instead).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you named dir for example `values-zh` it will be loaded only when Chinese is chosen in  system language settings. You should know about that.

Value `zh-rCN` is correct and everything should work correctly. Read my notice above.

Comment: values-zh works fine, but I need to differentiate between Simplified Chinese and Traditional Chinese. I tried to load the locale manually, using Locale and getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(). But still, if the values are in values-zh-rCN they are not being loaded. for some reason they are ignored. any idea why?

Comment: Did you read that article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself ?

Comment: @aviran use zh_CN if you want to load the contents of zh_rCN if you set the locale manually.

Answer (score 9):

Use following code its working for me for traditional and simplified chinese.

```
if(selectedLanguage.equals("zh_CN"))
    locale = Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE;
else if(selectedLanguage.equals("zh_TW"))
    locale = Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE;
else
    locale = new Locale(selectedLanguage);

Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
baseContext.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, baseContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct locales are `zh-rCN` and `zh-rTW`,so then whatever Android software your using isn't correctly setting locale values.

Look into settings -> Language & Input to double check that Language is on Chinese, and if that fails look in the market for an application called MoreLocales2, it allows you to get around some of those stock Samsung softwares that prevent locale changing from working.

Comment: This is incorrect. You should place your Chinese (Traditional) translations into values-zh so that locales other than zh-TW will still get Traditional Chinese translations. If your user is form Macau (zh_MO), or Hong Kong (zh_HK), and you don't include a values-zh directory, they would see English text instead of Traditional Chinese. Place your Simplified Chinese translation in values-zh-rCN because Simplified Chinese is used in fewer locales.

Comment: The user had asked for Simplified & Traditional which I provided. There was no mention in the OP about using `values-zh` or anything like that so thanks for the -1.

Comment: Exactly what I need. Thanks.