# How to change language in app on Android

Tags: android

My device system is set to Traditional Chinese.
But I want to my app default language as English.
So I use below code to set default before at first time.

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    Configuration config = res.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
```

But it still show Traditional Chinese but not English.
How can I modify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following in the AndroidManifest.xml for every activity

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)