# android refering pre defined resources folders

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

can I change the referring a **resource folders** programmaticaly. I need to use a language that is not supported by android, in my case Sinhala. can I create a **values_sin** folder and refer it when user select Sinhala language. can I change the **font** together with that for entire application.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: put your Sinhala strings in `res/values/strings.xml`, and the English strings in `res/values-en/strings.xml` or maybe even better, in `res/values-en-rIN/strings.xml`. When using the second method, your app will be in English only if the user selects "English (India)" as the phone's language. In any other case, the default resources will be used - which in your case will be in Sinhala!

Edit 2: actually, Android *does* support Sinhalese, using `res/values-si`. If you can't select Sinhalese as your device's default language, you could change it at runtime. There are plenty of posts already, such as [Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself?rq=1)

Comment: Android does not support sinhala. but you can add sinhala by placing .ttl sinhala font