# Localization for multilanguage in android

Tags: android, localization, multilingual

This question here is very helpful for me to start somehow. I have never tried localization of the application. So I am totally new here. But I am facing some problems still. 
I have list of languages like this;

```
<string-array name="languages">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Finnish</item>
    <item>French</item>
    <item>German</item>
    <item>Slovakian</item>
    <item>Polish</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to set default to English when the application starts. And when the language is changed I want the same language to be run through the whole activities. In the link above, in method  **public void setLocale(String localeCode)**, what will be the **localeCode** in my case. And what will be the locale code here,**Locale locale = new Locale(localeCode)**; . I know here might be **Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH)**; . I have done so far like this, I know this is crap because it is not working what I am expecting. Could you please help me a right path. Thanks in advance

```
public class Base_Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.getItem(0).getActionView()
            .findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.languages, R.layout.spinner_row);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        // private String currentLanguage;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            // currentLanguage = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

            Locale locale = null;
            switch (arg2) {
            case 0:
                locale = new Locale("en_US");
                break;
            case 1:
                locale = new Locale("fi");
                break;
            case 2:
                locale = new Locale("fr");
                break;
            case 3:
                locale = new Locale("de");
                break;
            case 4:
                locale = new Locale("sk");

                break;
            case 5:
                locale = new Locale("pl");
                break;

            default:
                locale = new Locale("en_US");
                break;
            }
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            startActivity();

        }

        private void startActivity() {
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            Log.i("DEBUG", "GATEWAY");

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

        }

    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}}
```

Comment: try by commenting  Locale.setDefault(locale);check the following link:    http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale%29

Comment: @Rama Could you please explain briefly. Don't get you.

Comment: Hoping The following link give you the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself

Comment: @Rama would you check my updated question above. I am not able to refresh the activity now. :(

Answer (score 0):

try this inside onITemSelectedListener

```
Locale locale = null ;

    switch (arg0) {
    case 0:
        locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
        break;
    case 1:
        locale = new Locale("fi"); 
        break;
    case 2:
        locale = new Locale("fr"); 
        break;
    case 3:
        locale = new Locale("de"); 
        break;
    case 4: 
        locale = new Locale("sk"); 

        break;
    case 5:
        locale = new Locale("pl"); 
        break;

    default:
        locale = new Locale("en_US"); 
        break;
    }

    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    this.getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

Comment: It is very hard for me to understand. c.locale = currentLanguage is not taking. It says changing the String currentLanguage to Locale, which is not possible. Could you explain me a bit briefly please.

Comment: shouldn't it be that switch (arg2), huh??

Comment: but still no progress :(

Comment: With this I got some changes. In first activity, when I try to change language it does not change here. But when I enter to next activity, it changes the selected language here. I need to say you that this activity is a base activity where all other activities are extended to base activity.

Comment: you didn't see any changes here coz after changing language you have to refresh activity

Comment: I know to do this i have to use finish(); then start activity (getIntent()); But it is blinking the screen. How to do this??

Comment: u can use overridePendingTransition(0, 0); with startActivity();

Comment: do not change anything:(. Can you check my updated question above please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47022/discussion-between-bshah-and-user88)

Comment: should the Indent start the activity which application start at the first sight ?

Answer (score 0):

check the way i have done.
 1.You have to create  different "values" folders for different languages under resources folder:
        ie... values--fr(for france), values-en(for engish)
 2. Now place   string  data for different languages in "string.xml" for relavent values folder

1. Then set data to views based on local language.
   when you change language then refresh your data fields as follows:

   gameTitle.setString(GameActivity.gameActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.Jimmy_Jigsaw);

   Hoping it will help you

Comment: I have so many strings, Do you want I do for each string as you are mentioning above. I have done all you have said before like making folders /res/values-en/strings.xml. When I select one language it does not refresh at the mean time. That's only my problem.