# Android : disable configuration changes

Tags: android

Our app translated to multiple languages, and I don't want that Android apply new configurations for activity when user changes language in system settings, user can choose language in application settings and it should remain no matter which language was chosen for the system. How to ignore changes of system language ?

Answer (score 2):

> How to ignore changes of system language ?

just do not provide `string.xml` file but for the default one and, write your own `Localization` Manager. I strongly discourage this kind of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the local from Your Application every time to Update the Configuration
You can this issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4239680/2764682