# Localisation in my Android App on button click?

Tags: android, button, android-activity, localization, textview

I have an android app and i have different activities and in that activities i have different textviews. I have two buttons of two languages one for English and another for chinese. Now i want to change all the textviews from different activities in another language as soon as user press chinese language.

Here is my one activity...

```
public class AndroidLocalize extends Activity {
 TextView tv;
 Button b1,b2;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("en"); 
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                tv.setText(R.string.greet);
            }
        });
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("hi"); 
                Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
                getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                tv.setText(R.string.greet);
            }
        });

    }
```

I am able to chnage the language on button click in the same activity now i want  to chnage the language in another activity also. here is my another activity..

```
public class Laanguage extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.language);
    TextView tv;
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
}
```

Comment: This thread might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself

Comment: I have changed the textview of my activity.But now i want to chnage the language of other textview that is in another activity..

Answer (score 0):

So for that you can use **Intent's** **putExtra** and **getExtra** methods in your main activity and sub activities respectively.

Comment: You can check out my updated code and how to chnage the language of another textview that is in different activity....

Answer (score 0):

You should save the chosen language to a SharedPreference and in `onCreate` of every Activity, get the language out and change the TextViews accordingly.

```
public class Statics {
    public static final String LANGUAGES_PREFS = "MyLanguagesPrefs";
}
```

When the user change the language to, let's say, English:

```
SharedPreferences language = getSharedPreferences(Statics.LANGUAGES_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = language.edit();
editor.putString("language", "English");
```

And in `onCreate` of every Activity:

```
SharedPreferences language = getSharedPreferences(Statics.LANGUAGES_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String language = language.getString("language", "");
// Change the TextViews
```

See more about [SharePreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).

Comment: Can you please just elaborate your answer..... Actually i got it but how to get language in every activity in oncreate....