# Font changes after configuration change

Tags: android

I have an app which allows you to switch between 2 different languages. I do that by updating the configuration and restarting the activity:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
language = lang;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
activity.recreate();
```

Now I have the problem that before switching the language the font sizes are displayed differently than after switching. See screenshots.
Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: so my understanding is for test purposes you are using only one locale and just making the config locale change and see how it is affecting the view. Correct me I am wrong?

Comment: I think so (your question is not totally clear to me)

Comment: Did u already check this link? If not could you look at that solution and see if that works? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself