# Android : Change entire app layout directions programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar, right-to-left, direction

How can I change entire app layout direction to RTL?
I am writing an app that user must select it's language in first launch and the layout should change based on user selection to RTL or remains LTR.
I used to add `android:supportsRtl="true"` to the `AndroidManifest` and `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` for each layout but this approach have some problems like below :

One problem is when I change the direction to RTL the `ActionBar` home icon or navigation button (when home as up is enabled) remains LRT and just move to the right.

I also tried to change direction programmatically and the result was the same :

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){
            getWindows().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
```

[image]

Is there any way to force all activities to become RTL at once or we should set direction in each activity separately?

Comment: Instead of asking the user to select a language at first launch, you could create multiple string resources for different languages (these would be put in different folders, e.g: `values`, `values-de`, `values-es`, `values-fr`, `values-it`, etc). The language set on the user's device would be automatically detected, and the correct strings/text would be displayed for that language. As well as this, the LTR or RTL layouts would be adjusted accordingly for that language.

Comment: I haven't language issue but the layout direction problem. Some users use they're devices with English but like they're local apps in they're native language. Assume I want to have a RTL layout with English language

Comment: did you find any solution ??

Answer (score 59):

You can use this piece of code while your application's **minSdk >= 17**.

I used `fa` for `Farsi`, you can use other *rtl* language.

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("fa"));
getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: It's no working. Please can you provide more code with explanation.

Comment: The code above is all I know and you must run it before calling `setContentView` to get it worked. What's the SDK version you are testing on?

Comment: Please check this issue for more information https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=219392&q=Rtl&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself

Comment: if it did not work you should add a string to another language and it works!

Comment: i dont want all my activity support RTL..How can i do for specific activites only.

Comment: @learner Just add `android:layoutDirection="rtl"` or `android:layoutDirection="locale"` to the top-level tag that is <LinearLayout> or <RelativeLayout> of your specific activities.

Comment: Nice, this works in combination with Robotium to take screenshots of Arabic locale. (Running on Android 5.1 emulator)

Comment: plz add this line: if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {

Answer (score 9):

Change the whole layout

```
 LinearLayout linrtl=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linrtl);
 linrtl.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Answer (score 7):

Try code below if you want to change language in the app and change directions in views and resources on active layout:

```
// set Persian language in the app
setLanguage(context, "fa");

public void setLanguage(Context c, String lang) {
    Locale localeNew = new Locale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(localeNew);

    Resources res = c.getResources();
    Configuration newConfig = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    newConfig.locale = localeNew;
    newConfig.setLayoutDirection(localeNew);
    res.updateConfiguration(newConfig, res.getDisplayMetrics());

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        newConfig.setLocale(localeNew);
        c.createConfigurationContext(newConfig);
    }
}
```

Also, after changing the language, you need to change the directions for the already created views on the active layout. You can do this with this code:

```
if (TextUtils.getLayoutDirectionFromLocale(Locale.getDefault()) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
        view.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
} else {
        view.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**The easiest and best way**
go to the `app/res/values/styles` and add below code to `<style>` tag, that you defined its name in android manifest
for example :

```
<style name"YourMainThemeName" parent="Parent Theme Of Your Choice">
    <item name="android:layoutDirection">rtl</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and now go to the `app/manifests/AndroidManifest.xml` and add below line code to `<application>` tag :

```
<application
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/YourMainThemeName">
</application>
```

now your layout directions is rtl and use `Toolbar` instead of `ActionBar` and define icon in the toolbar for arrowBack

Answer (score 4):

```
public class RtlActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("fa"));
        getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

extend other activities from this class instead of AppCompatActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends RtlActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //bla bla bla
    }
}
```

tnx Afshin.

Answer (score 3):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

Enter this code in `onCreate` java class of activity

Comment: Thank you, This code is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The back button stays in LTR mode, because it only has one resource, which is an arrow pointing to the left. You need to specify a new resource folder e.g drawable-ldrtl-hdpi and put the same icon which is pointing right in this folder.

Answer (score 1):

add this class:

```
public class LanguageHelper {

public static void changeLocale(Resources res, String locale) {

    Configuration config;
    config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

    switch (locale) {
        case "fa":
            config.locale = new Locale("fa");
            config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("fa"));
            break;
        case "en":
            config.locale = Locale.ENGLISH;
            config.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("en"));
            break;
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}

public static Locale getLocale(Resources res) {
    Configuration config;
    config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    return config.locale;
}
}
```

then use above class like this(in your activity):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //========set default language as persian:start==============
    LanguageHelper.changeLocale(this.getResources(), "fa");
    //========set default language as persian:end================

  ........
 }
```

and your layout will be RTL.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem, i find that if your view's width set `MATCH_PARENT`, you should set the view's gravity with `Gravity.LEFT` in *LTR* model and set the view's gravity with `Gravity.RIGHT` in RTL model.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work:

```
    Resources your_resource = context.getResources();

    Configuration config = your_resource.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = locale;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
        config.setLayoutDirection(locale);
    }
```

where locale is object of Locale