# Wrong direction of back arrow on toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I need supporting RTL languages on my application , problem is with back arrow on some devices specially samsung galaxy note 4. there is no problem on other devices so far but on note 4.
how can I change the direction on this device also?
this is how I do:

on manifest :

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

library :
I am using ***appcompatV7(latest one)***

drawable folder:
I added all folders from support library version 4 like drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi

drawable:
I am using android provided `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png` in every single drawable folder

code :

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>17)
    mToolBar.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

also I added this :
        `getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha);`

also in my **style.xml** there is :

```
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha</item>
```

With all of this, back arrow direction is ok on all devices so far except samsung galaxy note 4! Attached image is output on samsung note 4 which is wrong and back arrow should point to right instead of left
can somebody please help on this

[image: wrong direction! should point to right not left]
regards

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31963619/android-navigation-button-show-wrong-side-when-layout-direction-is-rtl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally fixed this by using this line of code :

```
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_arrow)
```

Comment: It works only if you have only light or dark toolbar in the whole app

Comment: so whats your suggestion @DawidHyży

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any clean solution

Comment: It works for me when I use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` and `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just right click drawable>New>Image Asset> Icon Type: Action Bar & Tab Icons... color your want.
and add this to your style

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     <!--... Your Style...-->
     <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_action_back</item>
 </style>
```

[image: Just right click drawable>New>Image Asset> Icon Type: Action Bar & Tab Icons...]