# Override supportsRtl manifest property programmatically

Tags: android, layout, configuration, right-to-left

Is there a way to set/override the supports-RTL property in Manifest at runtime in Android?
I wish to be able to switch the layout programmatically without actually changing the locale. 
From what I have searched, it looks like I'll have to set layout direction for Application and every activity. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

From [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049053/5137352) it is possible to change layout direction in all activities at once using a language with RTL layout direction. The answer uses `Farsi` language for RTL. You can use English if you want LTR.

Place the following code in the method `onCreate` of your launcher activity before calling `setContentView`:

```
Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
configuration.setLayoutDirection(new Locale("fa")); // Farsi for RTL
getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

**Old answer:**

You can get the reference of decor view in each activity and set its layout direction.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
}
```

To make this process shorter, put the above code inside `onCreate` method of a common class `BaseActivity` which extends `AppCompatActivity` and use all activities as its subclasses.