# Android language change in onConfigurationChange method

Tags: android, android-activity, locale, android-configchanges

i am using the following code in my onConfigurationChange mehtod of MainActivity

```
Locale locale = new Locale(getDefault().getLanguage());
Locale.setDefault(locale);  
Configuration config = new Configuration();  
config.locale = locale;  
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
```

And when user selects a different language through Settings the onConfigurationChange method is called but language does not change though other activities opened after MainActivity have the language changed.

My MainActivity is the Activity which remains open throughout the app session

The only way i am able to change language is when the MainAcitivity calls onCreate method but i dont want that as i hav my bluetooth pairing enabled in MainActivity which connects to other bluetooth device whenever onCreate is called i.e only once throughout the app session.

Comment: You have to redraw an activity in order to see the language change, is not needed to call oncreate again, just calling setContentView again should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already answered your own question, when `onConfigurationChanged` is triggered, it doesn't automatically update everything. You need to do that manually.

I suggest moving the layout setup from `onCreate` to another method and call this new method from both `onCreate` and `onConfigurationChanged`. Do not forget to also set all the values programatically (i.e. strings) if the strings are only on the layout using @string/xxx.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this question: 
[Changing Locale within the app itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264874/changing-locale-within-the-app-itself)

It helps you to change language in all activities and also not from `onCreate()`