# Android - support Rtl pre api 17

Tags: android, localization

I need change my layout direction Rtl when locale changed to arabic

According to documentation I found all I need just

I need to add both left and start the same to right and end

I did that but when I run at api 16 I found layout direction not changed

> If you want your app to work with versions earlier than Android 4.2
>   (the app's targetSdkVersion or minSdkVersion is 16 or less), then you
>   should add “start” and end” in addition to “left” and “right”. For
>   example, you’d use both android:paddingLeft and android:paddingStart.

Ref : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

I found some people taking about create separate layout files for api 17 and above but I dont think this good approach to follow

any one could help me how to fix this issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32037685/2693869
This works with both pre and post api 17