# Android - Forced locale reset on orientation changes

Tags: android, locale, orientation

I try to force the locale in my app to one the user specified. As this may be used to demonstrations, I want to change the language/locale in the app and not anytime for the whole device.

I looked around SO and tried to use every hint I found here. The result: I can restart my test activity with the new language, but if I change the orientation, the locale will always be reseted to the device one.

I [uploaded a minimalistic project](http://martin.cyor.eu/TestProject.zip) so you can reproduce my issue. Please ignore the shrinking of the UI, it's not important :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the reset of the locale occurring because your Activity is being restarted on orientation change?

If so, you can *intercept or prevent orientation changes*: [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)

Comment: I "restart" my Activity with finish() and startActivity() to force the reload of the UI which use the new locale. The orientation change always resets my locale

Answer (score 10):

This code snippet does what you need, I've tested it. Suppose for the example you want the user to be able to switch language through a menu from your main activity. You can do it through saving a language flag as a user preference and check it on "onCreate()" and on "onConfigurationChanged()" as follows:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

SharedPreferences mPrefs1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPrefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String languageToLoad = mPrefs1.getString("languagePref", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mPrefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String languageToLoad = mPrefs1.getString("languagePref", Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

// Declaring the Menu options
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{       
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

//handle menu item selection
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_switch_language:
        String languageToLoad  = getResources().getString(R.string.switch_language);

        mPrefs1 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs1.edit();
        editor.putString("languagePref", languageToLoad);
        editor.commit(); // Very important to save the preference                      
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
}
```

}

Comment: `Resources#updateConfiguration` is deprecated,

Use `Context#createConfigurationContext(Configuration)`

Answer (score 3):

I just saw your code.

Check that the `Locale` you are using is from java.util and not from android. Your code will not change the locale of the cellphone.

To test it:

- I set my phone to Spanish.
- Open your app
- click the button
- go to home
- Icons were in spanish instead of english.

If what you are trying to do is just setting the Locale to a default and being able to see the same value after a screen rotation:

Instead of:

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

use:

```
android:configChanges="locale|orientation"
```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is setting the locale right before you inflate your layouts :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String userLocale = "Wolof"; // adapt to your need
    Locale locale = new Locale(userLocale);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should force your locale in **Application::onCreate** and **Application::onConfigurationChanged**.
Do not forget to register your Application class in **AndroidManifest.xml**