# Save language when the screen is rotated

Tags: java, android, android-orientation

I'm using this below method to change the language of the app by passing the language code as string.
When I change the screen orientation the language rests to default language and all views resets too.

```
 public String setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
    return lang;
}
```

I tried to use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`, but I don't know how to make all these methods work together.

Comment: save your current language in permanent storage and implement onOrientationChanged method in your code and in it check for language and update accordingly

Comment: Store current language in SharedPreferences and when screen orientation changed set language from SharedPreferences  Also check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324418/android-forced-locale-resetted-on-orientation-changes

Answer (score 0):

Using shared preferences you can store the lanuage and get the stored value on screen orientation change.

```
public String setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
    finish();
    // save shared preference here or later, your choice.
    return lang;
}
```

Code to create and save shared preference.

```
SharedPreferences  preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor nameEditor = preferences.edit();
nameEditor.putString("saved_lang", lang);
nameEditor.commit();
```

Code to retrieve value of shared preference.

```
//To get language when screen changes.
String lang = preferences.getString("saved_lang", "");
```

You can use the [same principal to save other values and settings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).