# Changing language for android device

Tags: android, device

How i can change the language for the device programmatically. I am not asking for changing language in a single application, in all the applications, just like what we do via settings on the phone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596352/change-language-settings-locale-for-the-device - atleast answer-wise.

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android