# How to change mapview language in android?

Tags: android, android-mapview

In my application,i am use `MapView`. but it display map in **English** language,but I want to display `MapView` in **Hebrew** language.

Like [THIS](http://maps.google.co.jp/?hl=ja).

How it possible in android?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this link.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596352/change-language-settings-locale-for-the-device

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your phone language settings.
You can change language settings in code, but not forget to change to default after closing your app.

```
Resources standardResources = getApplicationContext();
DisplayMetrics metrics = standardResources.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration config = new Configuration(standardResources.getConfiguration());
config.locale = new Locale("ja") // change
standardResources.updateConfiguration(config, metrics);

// in onDestroy()
config.locale = Locale.getDefault(); // default
standardResources.updateConfiguration(config, metrics);
```