# How to start activity Language and input

Tags: android, set, settings

I want to open (start) activity named: "Language and input", where the user can change the device language.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Locale....));
```

It's in the Locale or... settings? Where is it?

Comment: I think this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596352/change-language-settings-locale-for-the-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change language settings (locale) for the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596352/change-language-settings-locale-for-the-device)

Answer (score 11):

try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent( new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.Settings$InputMethodAndLanguageSettingsActivity" ));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation about how your code does solve the problem.

Comment: Note that for Android 8.0 (Oreo, API Level 26) this will throw ActivityNotFoundException. Instead, try using `com.android.settings.Settings$LanguageAndInputSettingsActivity`.

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS open input method not language and input

Answer (score 7):

Use this for open language and settings..

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
startActivity(i);
```

it will work

Comment: "Language and Input" activity, using   android.provider.Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS

Comment: Is it possible to limit the languages shown there to specific languages that the application provides the translation only?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative answer, you can use this:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS), 0);
```

It will bring you to the system language menu.

Or this for keyboards and inputs:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INPUT_METHOD_SETTINGS), 0);
```

When the user hits the back button, it will return to your app.