# Going to Phone Settings when a button is clicked

Tags: android, settings

How can I make my app lead to the Phone settings more specific - to the Language settings when a button is clicked ?

I have got the button in an xml and everything ready but I do not know what to write in MainActivity.java to make it lead to the Settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start activity Language and input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162873/how-to-start-activity-language-and-input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS),0);
```

to your button's function or OnClick event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in your onClick event (it takes you directly to the Language & Input settings page your Android device:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$InputMethodAndLanguageSettingsActivity");
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Just a note: Valentin's answer below takes you directly to the device language selection screen whereas mine takes you to the Language and Input screen with all the options.