# How to open IME settings? Android Keyboard AOSP

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-settings

I would like to provide the possibility to change some settings of the Android keyboard (only this keyboard).

---

What I've tried:

**[1. Accessing the Shared Preferences:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16559531/2110483)** Can't be done, because they are internally.

**[2. Start the SettingsActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2210073/2110483)**: This crashes because the `SettingsActivity` is not `exported`. I also tried starting it with the package context of the Android keyboard.

**[3. Open the settings:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790046/2110483)** Android proviedes some possibilities to open the system settings. But with them I can only open the system settings and not the IME settings.

Based on the [documentation](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#DefiningIME) the `SettingsActivity` should receive an intent filter for ACTION_MAIN that indicates this activity is the main entry point for the IME application.

---

**Can I change the settings of the keyboard somehow by myself? If this is not possible can I open the `SettingsActivity`?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm using LatinIME and this is how i open the settings

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_SHOW_HOME_AS_UP, false);
intent.putExtra(SettingsActivity.EXTRA_ENTRY_KEY,false);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Are you using the LatinIME as library or where do you get the SettingsActivitiy?

Comment: i'm developing an costume keyboard using the Android Opensource files for latinIME. which can me found [link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME/) 
i understand my answer might not help you at all. I didnt understood correctly at  first that you are trying to open the settins from another app.

Comment: I would like to open the default Android keyboard settings, but this seems impossible.