# What are the differences between the two methods which both get Locale object

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

In android, I can get `Locale` instance either by:

```
Locale locale = getContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale;
```

Or by:

```
Locale.getDefault().toString();
```

Anyone can make a **concrete explanation** about the **differences between these two** ?

Is it so that one is for app level locale while the other is system locale ?

Another question: is there a way to change device level locale programmatically? (**Not app level locale**)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [android documentation for Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html):

> You can use getDefault() to get an appropriate locale for the *user* of
>   the device you're running on

Andr from the [android documentation for Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)

> **locale:**   Current user preference for the locale

So yes, the `.getConfiguration()` locale is an app-based user preference, whereas the `getDefault()` locale is a (still user specific) device level selection.

Comment: Thanks, by the way, I know how to change app level locale, but is there a way to change device level locale programmatically?

Comment: Not that I know of... **edit** similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596352/change-language-settings-locale-for-the-device)