# Programmatically change a resource string?

Tags: android, string

can I programmatically change `<string name="title_activity_quiz">QuizActivity</string>`
and even more important, will it be updated in the action bar?

Comment: Why you want to do that ? It cannot be done

Comment: Consider using a string array, instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change value of R.string programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programmatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> strong text Programmatically change a resource string?

If you are asking for how to change String resource content (during runtime) - no you cannot do that. **Resources are created once** (defined in XML files) and no more.

Instead of you can easily create another String resource and switch between them whenever you want it:

```
getActionBar().setTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.id.secondString));
```

Comment: This is my class,`public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {` how can I refer to getActionBar()?

Comment: Look at [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html).

Comment: great thanks! I did it, but it tells me min sdk is 11, mine is 8. But I have the support libs..

Comment: @user3385402 yes, then you can call `getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: I have imported the appcompat_v7, and my activity extend ActionBarActivity

Comment: hey geralt :-) you seem to be very experienced. do you know whether you can give a bundle when a button is clicked? like when button 1 is clicked an int with value 1 is given to the listener?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could have two string resources and change dynamically the title of the ActionBar with `getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.your_new_resource))`.