# How to set Different String in a Textview in Fragment while clicking different Button?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-button

I'm new to Android app programming.

I have two Fragments - `fragmentA.xml` and `fragmentB.xml`.

In `fragmentA` there are two Buttons - Button One (id: `btnOne`) and Button Two (id: `btnTwo`).

In `fragmentB` there is TextView (id- `textView`)

In `fragmentB` java class there are two `String` - `string1` and `string2`

Both buttons refers to `fragmentB`.

I want two set the `textView` text to `string1` when I press Button One 
and `string2` when I press Button Two.

How can I do that?

I was using following code in `fragmentB` java class to display only `string1`

```
public View onCreateView(
    LayoutInflater inflater, 
    ViewGroup container, 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.oop_page,container,false);
    TextView textV = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    textV.setText(string1);
    return rootView;
}
```

Can I use any if-else statement here?

Thanx

Comment: "Both Buttons refer to FragmentB" what does this mean?

Comment: make only one string in your global class (accessible to both fragment) and set it to your textview,....just change string on button click it will be automatically disply changed one...

Comment: @AnshulJain I use a method to open the FragmentB and I am using the method in Button One and Button Two's onClick method

Comment: have you tried what i have suggested

Comment: @Mohit you mean i should declare a string in MainActivity.java . can you provide me the code. and what if there is more than two botton. I mean for every button different string.

Comment: it deos not matter how many button you have,you will need only one string till you want to display one...

Comment: let me test. I'll inform you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102501/discussion-between-mohit-and-maxyspark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `Global` class in your project and define a **public** string ..

```
public class Global{
  public static String TEXT = "";
}
```

In your `Fragment A` change this `TEXT` on button click event..

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Global.TEXT = "string 1";
    }
});
but2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Global.TEXT = "string 2";
    }
});
```

same as on other button if you have

In  your `FragmentB` just `setText()`....it will take lase value change to `Text`

```
text.setText(Global.TEXT);
```

Comment: it worked. can I use string from string.xml resource file?

Comment: i would not suggest that because you can get what i stored in string but you can modifiy during run time..have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programically) post...

Answer (score 0):

**FragmentA.java**

```
public boolean btn1Clicked, btn2Clicked = false;
        Button button1 = (Button) rootViewfindViewById(R.id.button1);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                btn1Clicked = true;
              }
            });

            Button button2 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                btn2clicked = true;
              }
            });
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
 public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater, 
        ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.oop_page,container,false);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        if(!(FragmentA.btn1Clicked))
         {
        // Not Clicked
         }
        else{
           tv1.setText("Button 1 Clicked!")'
    }
        return rootView;
    }
```