# Want to get title and date of checked CheckBox from ExpandableListView when Click on submit Button

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-checkbox

> I created `ExpandableListView` with `titles` and `checkBox` as `GroupItem` and `Due Date` and `date` as child Item..
>
> I want to get Only `_title_`(Monthly Return Filing in Form 10) and `_date_`(15th of Next Month) of checked `checkBoxes` when user select them and click on `submit` button

**My BaseExpandableListAdapter**

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Group_Items gr = (Group_Items) getGroup(groupPosition);
    long group_id = getGroupId(groupPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.expandable_group_items, null);

        // adding onClick listener on CheckBox for the very first time
        chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
        chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int position = (int) v.getTag();
                mSelections.put(position, !mSelections.get(position, false));
                ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(mSelections.get(position, false));
            }
        });
    }

    final TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setText(gr.getName());
    CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk);
    chk.setTag(groupPosition);

    // reassigning checkbox to its ticked state
    chk.setChecked(mSelections.get(groupPosition, false));
    });
    if (groupPosition==7){
        chk.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return convertView;
    }else {
        chk.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**My FirstRow.java**

```
public class FirstRow extends AppCompatActivity {
private MyBaseExpandableListAdapterFirstRow ExpAdapter;
private ArrayList<Group_Items> ExpListItems;
private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
Child_Items ch;
Button submit_info;
Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.expandable_listview);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    
    alertDialogmsg();

    ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.exp_lv);
    ExpListItems = setAllData();
    ExpAdapter = new MyBaseExpandableListAdapterFirstRow(FirstRow.this, ExpListItems);
    ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);

    submit_info= (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit_info);
    submit_info.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
}

private void alertDialogmsg() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setTitle("Select Taxes");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Please select applicable section only to avoid unnecessary reminders");
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}

private ArrayList<Group_Items> setAllData() {

    String group_titles[] = {
            "Payment of Employer and employees contribution",
            "Monthly Return Filing in Form 5 and Declaration in form 2",
            "Monthly Return Filing in Form 10",
            "Monthly Return Filing in Form 12",
            "Statement of Recovery from contractor",
            "Annual Return in Form 6A",
            "Submission of contribution card of employees leaving services",
            "Renewal of contribution card of an employee by filing Form 3 & 3A"};

    String child_info[] = {
            "We have deployed secured web services framework in accordance with OASIS standards. Please refer the user manual (Secured Web service user manual) under the help section and do the necessary changes at your end to start consuming the same. Existing web services shall be discontinued w.e.f 1-Dec-2015",
            "Return of employees qualifying for membership",
            "Return of members leaving the services during the month",
            "Statement of contribution",
            "Self Explnatory",
            "Consolidated annual contribution statement",
            "Self Explnatory",
            "Self Explnatory"};

    String dates[] = {
            "15th of Next Month + 5 Days Grace period",
            "15th of Next Month",
            "15th of Next Month",
            "25th of Next Month",
            "7th of Next Month",
            "30th April",
            "20th of Next Month",
            "Within one month on the expiry of contribution card currancy to the commissioner"};

    ArrayList<Group_Items> list = new ArrayList<Group_Items>();
    ArrayList<Child_Items> ch_list= new ArrayList<Child_Items>();
    ch = new Child_Items();
    int i=0;
    int size=1;

    for (String group_title : group_titles) {
        Group_Items gru = new Group_Items();

        gru.setName(group_title);

        ch_list = new ArrayList<Child_Items>();
        for (; i < size; i++) {
            Child_Items ch = new Child_Items();

            ch.setChild_title(child_info[i]);
            ch.setDd("Due Date:");
            ch.setDate(dates[i]);

            ch_list.add(ch);
        }

        gru.setItems(ch_list);
        list.add(gru);
        size=size+1;
    }
    return list;
}
```

}

**My Stack Trace**

```
-14 13:29:13.985 26489-26489/neoxsoft.com.taxmukti E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: neoxsoft.com.taxmukti, PID: 26489
                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                       at neoxsoft.com.taxmukti.allsubtaxes_first.FirstRow.MyBaseExpandableListAdapterFirstRow.getChildView(MyBaseExpandableListAdapterFirstRow.java:64)
                                                                       at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2318)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1824)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:717)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1375)
                                                                       at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1642)
                                                                       at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2139)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1697)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1551)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1460)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1697)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1551)
                                                                       at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1460)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                       at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                       at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14846)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4664)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2010)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1767)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1018)
                                                                       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5756)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                                       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
                                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> I took `submit_info` button in my `FirstRow.java` and want to get values of selected `CheckBox` when click on `submit` button with `onClickListener` So, guys how to get values of the same please help me..

Comment: can you post your constructor? and what is `gru.setItems(ch_list);`

Comment: @Mohit here  is my constructor... `public MyBaseExpandableListAdapterFirstRow(Context context, ArrayList<Group_Items> group_al) {
        this.context=context;
        this.group_al=group_al;
    }`

Comment: what type `gru.setItems` return?

Comment: @Mohit  `gru` is a object of `Group_Items` class which contains `getter` and `setter` method and `setItems` is one of the setter method from that `Group_Items` class So, gru `setItems` on list..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get your group name by `String` in array list at `groupPosition` you are passing to constructor and you child date by getting `getDate()` at `childPosition` of `getItems` at `groupPosition`...

On your submit button call like...

```
String name = group_al.get(groupPosition).getName();
String date = group_al.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition).getDate();
```

Comment: this will return name and date of check box clicked

Comment: Where I put my button? in my FirstRow.java or in BaseExpandableListAdapter.java??

Comment: in your `getGroupView`

Comment: where you are using button?

Comment: in `FirstRow.java` not in the `CustomAdapter`

Comment: ok make a global arraylist  [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35183420/2553431)  where you can store your all check value...and use it on submit button..

Comment: insted of that now I am put my code in `custom Adapter` but it shows error at `String date = group_al.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition).getDate();` as can not resolve symbol childPosition

Comment: I will try sir wait a second

Comment: If I place that code in childView then `groupPosition` of both line show error

Comment: `groupPosition` is first parameter in your `getChildView` method

Comment: ok sir I write code in `getChildView` but application is unfortunatly stopped when click on `row`(title)

Comment: and sir Can I get values from using `if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()){
                    }` code in getGroupView??/

Comment: I will upload my stack trace shortly.... but can I get checked items in onclicklistener of checkbox in groupview

Comment: you wont get child position there

Comment: Sir I posted my Stack trace plz check it

Comment: what is line:64 in your `MyBaseExpandableListAdapterFirstRow`

Comment: `btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() `    It shows error at `btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String name = group_al.get(gp).getName();
                String date = group_al.get(gp).getItems().get(cp).getDate();
            }
        });` this statement

Comment: i can not error your log ....just upload you main class,adapter,setter class some where (drive)... send link so I can check what causing error

Comment: ok sir I upload it on drive plz check this [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4WLNcB0KW3HOHhHRkJrUFFjZGs&usp=sharing)

Comment: does `submit_info` button belongs to `expandable_child_items` layout

Comment: no it is on `expandable_listview.xml` below the `expandableListView`

Comment: you can not call button if it  do not belong  to `expandable_child_items`

Comment: sir, How I get that selected values now

Comment: any solution for that sir

Comment: i think you should use check box at child not at group ,because if you are put there you have to get all child text value not single one...

Comment: but sir client wants it at GroupPosition

Comment: It is possible to get all selected values in FirstRow. java file

Comment: no sir only selected child date and group title only

Comment: how will you select child date if you do not have check box there..?

Comment: I think in `getGroupView` by using `onClickListener` on `CheckBox` I can access them.. Is it possible?

Comment: how it will know child click on which position ?

Comment: as you can not get child position there

Comment: what i will do sir. I am so confused now tomorrow is a Deployment date

Comment: you have put check box in child, so when you click it you gets its position....else only option is to get all text of child

Comment: ok Sir.. Can I get two `checkboxes` one at `group position` and another at `child` next to date... and when click on `group position`  `check box` then `child position` `checkbox` will be checked.

Comment: I will add another `CheckBox` next to `child` item but how it is possible to when user Check `checkbox` of Group item then `CheckBox` of child item also get Checked? There is any Logic for that

Comment: check if current group position check box is check and if it is ,then setcheck to all of check box inside child

Comment: take a boolean variable, at `chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener())` true this boolean, and on your `getChildView` check all checkbox if this boolean is true else uncheck all...

Comment: not in answer but in my customadapter.java file and again send it to me with drive link

Comment: chek [this link](http://www.filedropper.com/mybaseexpandablelistadapterfirstrow-copy)

Comment: sir I get Your code now I will add the `checkbox` in `childview` and check it out

Comment: thank you sir I added `checkbox` to the child view by default it is `checked` now how I collect values when group items is selected

Comment: no sir now they told me that first make your ui best then work on database so,  I am not check is that work or not but after completing design I will check

Comment: Also they told me you can get checkbox in child view but it should be hidden... is it possible sir?? after hiding it can I store value of that childview in database

Comment: yes but that could be another question......and yes my answer answer helped you in any way ..you can upvote or accept it....

Comment: ok sir. I will upvote your answer. please answer me if I had any problems in future

Answer (score 0):

Seems the `mSelections` in your adapter already keeps checked positions with some data, but it only adds data to it when check box is checked but doesn't remove the data from it when unchecked.

You have a `View.OnClickListener` set on the check box, you can get the checked status from `((CheckBox) v).isChecked()`. Then update the `mSelections` accordingly.

Now you can make a public method on the adapter to get a list of selected `Group_Items` via the `mSelection` which contains all the checked positions, the same as the indices of the underlying data list.

`View.OnClickListener` is not ideal. Because check box has its own [`OnCheckedChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener)), you don't have to cast the `view` to a check box to get check status.

Comment: I am little bit confused can you give me some code to explain it