# Hold items in list

Tags: android, listview

I have made changes as suggested and it's working fine.but I have put button mainactivity to go to main2activity to check list but it's giving error.
This is my code and button to check list is R.Id.viewlist

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 EditText editText;
  Button addButton;
      @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
     final EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
     Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
             intent.putExtra("text", editText.getText().toString());
             startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
     Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.viewlist);
     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
              startActivity(intent);
         }
     });
```

main2acctivity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
   @Override
 protected void onRestart() {
     super.onRestart();
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Global.list1);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     if (Global.list1.size()<1){
         Global.list1=new ArrayList<>();
     }
  }
  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
     Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
       Intent intent1= getIntent();
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
          adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Global.list1);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
     Global.list1.add(intent1.getStringExtra("text"));
      adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
```

Global. Class

Comment: Create a global arraylist and add item to it so your list will be automatically update when you update the arraylist

Comment: I'm new to Android can you help me out with how to create global array list.please

Comment: Yes sure...have a look at my [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35183420/2553431) answer ..this is similer to your problem ....post if you still face problem....

Comment: Yeah please post your answer. Thanks

Comment: Buddy I am on my phone..so here is what you do. First create a class `Global` , there declare arraylist like `public static ArrayList<String> _LIST =new ArrayList<String>();` and use this arraylist instead of your `listItems`...like `Global._LIST.add("");`....hope it helps...

Comment: Thank you for answer I'll try it

Comment: I tried but it still not working. Can anyone give me solution

Comment: can you post your global class and the way you are adding to arraylist

Comment: public class Global {     public static ArrayList<String>list1=new ArrayList<String>();  }

Comment: This is my global class

Comment: why not use shared preferences? Save the data in the onPause of your activity and load it in when the you fire up the other activity. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: so your is solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override the onRestart metod of your activity and put in the code for populate the list view with the global array.

```
@Override
public void onRestart()
{
super.onRestart();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Global.list1);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And maybe you don't want to do this

```
Global.list1 = new ArrayList();
```

Instead, you should do this

```
if(Global.list1.size()<1)
{
Global.list1 = new ArrayList();
Global.list1.add("First Item - added on Activity Create");
}
```

**EDIT:**
For the new problem:

```
//In the Main2Activity
String haveString=intent1.getStringExtra("text");
if(haveString!=null)
   {
   Global.list1.add(haveString);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Comment: Now I put one button to view list in mainactivity to see list. I sat on click listener to open main2activity but it's showing error.

Comment: Update the post to put in your new problems and i will update my answer if i know how to solve them. Put in the post the code and the error message from the log. If the answer is helping you chose it like the apropiate one.

Comment: I have updated my question. The new button which I have put to go to main2activity to check list giving me problem.

Comment: I edit the answer with the new possible solution. If it dosn't solve the problem put the log error.

Comment: Thanks buddy I'll try this

Comment: Thanks a lot dude.It's working all fine. I'm thankful to you

Comment: No ptoblem. If this answer solve the problem, please mark it like the correct answer.

Comment: Buddy what if I put one more edit text in mainactivity and have to add data in same manner

Answer (score 0):

why not use shared preferences? Save the data in the onPause of your activity and load it in when the you fire up the other activity. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html.

You could also solve this using multiple fragments and save the state of the app in the activity that contains both fragments I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you want to persist this list just within the app use session (meaning if they close the app, the list would reset from the beginning. If that is the case, you would want to use a "SharedPreferences" and store your items in a list that maps to a field in SharedPreferences.
If that is the case, you can go [here](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/arraylist-in-sharedpreferences/):

This will show you how to store an array list of items that persists even if the user restarts the app and goes back to that 2nd activity.

Otherwise, if you don't want to have a persistence across app sessions/restarts, then you can actually just use a Global Singleton to store list of sorts as was suggested above.

```
 public static class GlobalListStorage {
     private static GlobalListStorage instance = null;
     public ArrayList<String> mItems=new ArrayList<String>();
     protected GlobalListStorage() {
     }

     public GlobalListStorage getInstance() {
         if (instance == null) {
             instance = new GlobalListStorage();
         }
         return instance;
     }
 }
```

Now when you want to add items to your list, you would do the following in your MainActivity.java, in your button click listener.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
        GlobalListStorage.getInstance().mItems.add(editText.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Now in your ArrayListAdapter, make sure to use the GlobalListStorage.getInstance().mItems as your arrayList that is supposed to be used.