# Change string value using putBoolean return a numeric value in android?

Tags: android, boolean, sharedpreferences

I have string field `<string name="categegoriesStatus">true</string>`

Now inside settingsActivity I am changing its value on preference click.

```
final SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.categegoriesStatus), false );
                        editor.apply();
```

But it is not changing it to false, but change it to some numeric value. And I don't get my desired result.

Comment: what's the numeric value your call returns?

Comment: @ChampS it returns value = 2131238702

Answer (score 1):

You have a **string**, but you want to **save a boolean**. Then, you should be this:

```
  boolean result = getResources().getString(R.string.categegoriesStatus).equals("true");
  editor.putBoolean(result, false );
```

Good luck!

Comment: I got 'Wrong first argument type. Boolean required'
in the 'result' variable.

I did this : editor.putBoolean(String.valueOf(result), false);
But it won't work.

Comment: You can try cast result to Boolean object. Maybe `(Boolean) result`? or `Boolean result = getResources().getString(R.string.categegoriesStatus).equals("true");`

Answer (score 1):

You are using Sharedpreferences wrongly.

in the statement editor.putBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.categegoriesStatus), false );
you are inserting editor.putBoolean("true", false); which is not what you are expecting it to do.

Information stored in shared preferences should be in key value format.

Read the android documentation from this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences only saves/retrieve key value pairs. It does not change your string resource values. Once you have declared a string resource field, you cannot change it's value at runtime. Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9679336/4244598).