# Change App Icon & Name Dynamically

Tags: android

I have developed an Android application and installed it on a device. I want to fetch app icon as well as app name from a server dynamically while the application is running. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you can't change it dynamically

Comment: I want to download the icon from server,and replace the origin one.I am not sure if it's possible,so I ask a question.But now, it seems impossible.Thanks

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the application's name & icon are hardcore in manifest file. And these values are hardcore ones. We can't change it once it's made. We can't change Raw values.
See this post,

[Changing of raw values programatically.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Since application's name & icon are hardcore in manifest file,but we can't change the manifest file. Also, we can't change the res file when the app has installed. So it is impossible to change the icon & name.

But, if the icon & name are already in the res file, we can change them,see this:[How to change an application icon programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103027/how-to-change-an-application-icon-programmatically-in-android)

Maybe there is a solution by Hook,plug-ins or Hot fix?