# Can I Change value string name in String.xml using edittext?

Tags: java, android

Can I Change value string name in String.xml using edittext?

Excample  `<string name="OK">GOOD</string>` to `<string name="OK">BAD</string>`

I am working with Android studio.

Comment: No. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9679336/421467

Comment: You cannot modify resources at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programmatically