# How can put into strings.xml from bakcend java android

Tags: android, android-resources

I need to put value from android backend java class to the strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="test">xyz</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi, please consider adding more information, what are you trying to achieve, what is your expected outcome, what have you tried? Expanded code blocks to give us an ability to try and replicate your issue.

Comment: You can not modify resources dynamically which are pre-bundled with apk . you certainly can get the String from server only if that's a dynamic data . Also you probably have do localization yourself if you call an API for data .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change value of R.string programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674925/change-value-of-r-string-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible you can't do that