# Programmatically change the value of a color resource obtained from API response

Tags: android, android-resources, aapt

Let's say, on my API call I have a parameter that's called `color`. Is it possible to edit or modify an existent `R.colors.color` to assign the color from the API result?

As an example:

I make a call to my API and it returns `green`, now I want to load my app with i.e (green `Toolbar`, green `TextView` color, etc.), is that possible?

My first thought was:

Create a item on `colors.xml` called `demo` then assign it a default color, then use this `demo` color wherever I want (`Button`, `TextView`, etc.) Then I thought it could be possible to change this value programmatically with the result from the API so I wouldn't need to create a `SharedPreferences` or something like that and for avoiding more code.

As [@Y.S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3287204/y-s) said to me

> Unfortunately, you WILL have to set the color of the text or view manually everywhere ... :(

I would like if there is other way to do it, since I don't know how many `Activities` my project will contain, so if is there other way to do it I'm glad to hear other guesses.

### EDIT

I'm trying the @Jared Rummler answer and maybe i'm doing something wrong... I've created a simple `Json` and I put on my Assets I parse the `Json` and I put it on a `GlobalConstant` then I made a "simple app".

First of all I have a `TextView` and a `Button` which contains the "your_special_color", and the return of it I put the `GlobalConstant int` as follows :

```
case "your_special_color":                
            return GlobalConstant.color;
```

Then what I tried is my first `Activity` has 1 `TextView` and 1 `Button` as I said before and they have the color "your_special_color" that I don't want to change it, BUT I have an `Intent` on my `Button` to open the other `Activity` that contains the same but with the `GlobalConstant.color` and it doesn't change.

I tried it doing this (my second Activity):

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Res res;
@Override public Resources getResources() {
    if (res == null) {
        res = new Res(super.getResources());
    }
    return res;
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Did I miss something?

Oh.. I figured it out I guess is doing this on my `MainActivity2` ?

```
 Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
 btn.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.your_special_color));
```

Comment: did you get the any solution on that  ?

Comment: Hey! Did you finally resolve this? I am facing a similar issue!

Comment: Follow the Jared solution it works I guess

Comment: Check out Cyanea to dynamically change primary and accent colors: https://github.com/jaredrummler/Cyanea

Comment: @JaredRummler Could you add a post to explain how Cyanea works? Thanks.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you take a look at the [Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) document, what it says is that ...

> Once you provide a resource in your application, you can apply it by referencing its resource ID. All resource IDs are defined in your project's `R` class, which the `aapt` tool automatically generates.

Furthermore,

> When your application is ***compiled***, `aapt` generates the `R` class,
>   which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your `res/`
>   directory. For each type of resource, there is an `R` subclass (for
>   example, `R.drawable` for all drawable resources), and for each
>   resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example,
>   `R.drawable.icon`). This integer is the resource ID that you can use
>   to retrieve your resource.

What this is saying, essentially, is that pretty much everything held as a *resource* in the `res/` directory is compiled and referenced as an unchangeable constant. It is for this reason that the values of resource elements cannot be changed programmatically/at runtime, because they are ***compiled***. As opposed to local/global variables & `SharedPreferences`, resource elements are represented in program memory as fixed, unchangeable objects. They are held in a special read-only region of program memory. In this regard, see also [**Changing value of R.String Programmatically**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9585029).

What you *can* do is, to avoid using the same code at a thousand places in your project, create a common function that changes the value of the color in the `SharedPreferences` and use this method everywhere. I'm sure you knew this already, of course.

To reduce the amount of code you need to add to the project, there is an alternative. I have previously used the [calligraphy library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) which allowed me to fix the font style & color throughout the app. This may be of some good use to you, check it out ...

Comment: So you are saying to me that its not possible to do that...? Then I'll have to create on each fragment on each activity the color to the view?

Comment: That's right, you can't do that. But you don't have to create the color repeatedly, you can create it in a common base class and keep the value as a global variable that you can use everywhere. Unfortunately, you **WILL**  have to set the color of the text or view manually everywhere ... :(

Comment: Yes that what I meant... I can save the value on sharedpref then create a globalclaas to declare the color but then... All of the setcolor set background are needed well... I'll try to find another solution somewhere if I don't find any I'll do what you say @Y.S.

Comment: With this from de api i can get a font aswell?

Comment: Do you mean that I can assign a font to the app and then declare the color?

Comment: See the use of the calligraphy library ... it lets you see the custom font in XML (this is not possible by default in Android). And it lets you set the fonts in an `Activity` without calling `setTypeFace()` everywhere. This may help make your work easier.

Comment: I started a bounty to see if it have other way to do it... otherwise, the bounty is for you ;)

Comment: see the answer that @Jared Rummler gave to me, it's that good?

Comment: Its an interesting idea, though at first glance I can't tell how it helps solve this problem ... :P

Comment: I'll test it, I saw that you've posted a comment in the answer I was wondering the same... let's see if he replays to your question :)

Comment: Did you hear about variant build?

Comment: I guess you mean build variant ... Yes, that is an approach, but that is not the same as changing values at runtime ...

Comment: Yo master @Y.S. if you have time let me know if you have any clue about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34889264/recyclerview-add-emptyview/34889332?noredirect=1#comment57517283_34889332)

Comment: Hey Skizo ... Of course I will see that question ... :)  Sorry for not replying to your last comment ... Do send me a reminder today evening if I forget ... Will definitely reply ... :)

Comment: Okay thanks, i think we together can solve the issue :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, Skizo ... I'm looking at that question now ... :)

Comment: how long can you try to help me out on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778920/move-an-imageview-on-screen-like-dragging)? :D

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46958600/create-service-to-detect-any-action-from-the-user) it's about services please :D

Comment: @Y.S have a question with bounty perhaps you can guide me how to, read the chat if you want for the answer answered already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376131/drag-and-drop-imageview-into-a-container-for-verification I know you can earn it! :D

Answer (score 81):

You can create a class which extends `Resources` and override the methods `getColor(int)` and `getColor(int, Theme)`.

### Example:

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="your_special_color">#FF0099CC</color>
</resources>
```

**Res.java**

```
public class Res extends Resources {

    public Res(Resources original) {
        super(original.getAssets(), original.getDisplayMetrics(), original.getConfiguration());
    }

    @Override public int getColor(int id) throws NotFoundException {
        return getColor(id, null);
    }

    @Override public int getColor(int id, Theme theme) throws NotFoundException {
        switch (getResourceEntryName(id)) {
            case "your_special_color":
                // You can change the return value to an instance field that loads from SharedPreferences.
                return Color.RED; // used as an example. Change as needed.
            default:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    return super.getColor(id, theme);
                }
                return super.getColor(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**BaseActivity.java**

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    private Res res;

    @Override public Resources getResources() {
        if (res == null) {
            res = new Res(super.getResources());
        }
        return res;
    }

    ...

}
```

---

This is the approach I have used in one of my apps, [Root Check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummyapps.rootchecker). If you override `getResources` in your activities and main application class you can change the theme programmatically (even though themes are immutable). If you want, download the app and see how you can set the primary, accent, and background colors from preferences.

Comment: thanks for your answer guy! I'll read it carefully and try to see if it's what I need, with this you think if I get a color (int) from an API call and I use on all of my backgrounds, styles, etc... my default color it will show the color of the API?

Comment: I've downloaded it, I used it before didnd't know the dev of this app were here :P, amazing animation on the start... and yes, I saw how you change the colors but will it turn black the screen for a seconds? I only need to do this at the start of the APP...

Comment: @JaredRummler: I don't get it ... how does overriding `getColor()` help change the fixed values of resource elements at runtime ?

Comment: @Y.S. If you look at the code, it is checking the resource name. If it is a certain id, you can have `getColor` return a different color value. You could also do this for `getDrawable` or even `getString`.

Comment: @JaredRummler: true, but don't you still have to call getColor() for different views/widgets ?

Comment: @JaredRummler I mean I can use this : return Color.RED; as a result of my int color from api call?

Comment: @Skizo, if you follow my answer then `getResources().getColor(R.color.your_special_color)` will return red instead of what you set in `res/colors.xml`. If you want, I could probably publish a small example to GitHub. Your question is a little ambiguous. You want a color resource to return a different value you set programmatically, correct?

Comment: Well yes, I think you got it because it's pretty simple, first I created my app with a `default_value` and I used it on whole app (`ActionBar background`, `textColor`, etc...) So now, I want that if I get from my API the color `Purple` (for example), the `default_value` turn into `purple`, and I'm wondering if I'll have to do it for each view on my app... Because as Y.S. said to me, when you compile the APP it compiles the R class then the color is on it....

Comment: All views will use `getResources` from your `Activity` to get the color unless it uses a custom `ContextThemeWrapper` (from my experience this is only used in `AlertDialog`). Just follow the steps in the answer or I can publish a sample. I was thinking of open sourcing the theme change library I'm using in my app.

Comment: But let's say I have my styles with my custom color (toolbar, tabs, etc..) and my text color from my buttons, must I have to getResources from all of those widgets? @JaredRummler

Comment: @Skizo, I read your comments. It's hard to understand exactly what you are looking to do. Did you try out my answer?

Comment: @JaredRummler I'll try to explain it better... from my API i get a "red" color, and on MainActivity I get this "red" color, from here all right? ok, then on my APP I used to use "default" color for all of my widgets/views, and I would like to change the "default" to "red" (HEX, obviously).

Comment: I meant if I get the int from an API call wich is called on MainActivity how can I `return Color.RED;` return the correct color?

Comment: I won't be available for another 6 hours. Feel free to email me and I'll help you out. jared.rummler@gmail.com

Comment: @Skizo I'll reply later tonight

Comment: @JaredRummler I have overridden the method in my activity and application. I have  `<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>`, in my theme. I use `?attr/colorAccent` in xml, but it has no effect. I have overriden for case:"colorAccent" in the method you asked

Comment: Sorry guys, but this is now `DEPECRATED`

Comment: @JaredRummler can you send me sample code for change color of theme? my email divyesh_asd@ymail.com

Comment: @JaredRummler any alternative way? Now it has been deprecated

Comment: getColor(int, Theme) not calling

Comment: can u pls send me with example for this color changes.

Comment: I wrote a library that dynamically changes the background, primary and accent colors of an app. The library is currently not open but hopefully I can share it soon. The code above will not work on Android 6.0+ because many changes were made to Resources. Also, I no longer own the Root Check app linked in the answer.

Comment: Hello, does this method still work? I think it looks promising and I am trying to test it for intercepting `getColor(int id, Theme theme)`. If I understand correctly, does "your_special_color" correspond to a color name in `colors.xml`? Also, does the returned color (in the example, Color.Red), have to be a hardcoded value somewhere in colors.xml? I'm trying to change theme color based on a custom user choice. Any chance of replacing the ResourceEntryName's hex value perhaps?

Comment: Hi Guys, the approach @JaredRummler has suggested works but seems only when the color is applied programmaticaly.

Something like this:
```
val colorId: Int = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)  {
            resources.getColor(R.color.appBackground, theme)
        } else {
            resources.getColor(R.color.appBackground)
        }
        contentMain.setBackgroundColor(colorId)
```
The color applied in the XML is not queried by the method ` resources.getColor(...)`.

@JaredRummler please correct me if I am wrong. I have tested in on Android 10.

Comment: @JaredRummler can you share your way of how to change colours in a library when passed from parent application?

Answer (score 17):

`R` class is not supposed to be edited. It merely contains references to your resources.

You will need to set it manually. However, to reduce the burden of setting it manually you can try to use special libraries for preference saving, for instance:

- Saber - https://github.com/jug6ernaut/saber
- PreferenceBinder - https://github.com/denley/preferencebinder

(full list of similar libraries https://android-arsenal.com/tag/75)

---

Also, you might want to think about another way of applying styles and passing parameters - consider you would want to add some other parameters like height, width etc. For that purpose, you can define custom attribute in themes.xml/styles.xml:

```
<attr name="demoColor" format="reference|color" />
```

then define styles:

```
<style name="BaseActivity">
</style>
<style name="GreenActivity" parent="@style/BaseActivity">
    <item name="demoColor">#00cd00</item>
</style>
<style name="RedActivity" parent="@style/BaseActivity">
    <item name="demoColor">#ff0000</item>
</style>
```

then use that color in your xml like this:

```
... android:background="?demoColor" ...
```

and switch between `GreenActivity` and `RedActivity` styles in `Activity.onCreate`:

```
setTheme(isGreenStyle() ? R.style.GreenActivity : R.style.RedActivity)
setContentView(...)
```

With the above approach, you will be able to easily configure your styles in xml and it should be less code and easier to refactor in future. (You will still need to have one variable in preference to save whether you have green or red style)

---

Another way, if you want to show demos of your app with different colors is to use build variants / flavors for loading your app with different colors and styles (it is for build time - not runtime):

*app/src/main/res/colors.xml*

```
<resources>
    <color name="demoColor">#00cd00</color>
</resources>
```

*app/src/buildVariant/res/colors.xml*

```
<resources>
    <color name="demoColor">#ff0000</color>
</resources>
```

Now you can quickly switch between "main" and "buildVariant" in Build Variants menu and launch your app with different "demo" colors. The same way you can customize a lot of other attributes.

Search for "Build Variants" here http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Comment: Oh didn't hear about this... So I can change the value programmatically if I use the buildvariant?

Comment: @Skizo build variants / flavors are not for changing the value programmatically - they allow you to build and run your app with different styles/colors/resources. It seems I missed "programmatically" part from your questions :)

I will update my answer a bit.

It would help if you could specify real use of the functionality you are trying to implement. Maybe there's a better way to do it.

Comment: Well I just want to save the color, not the style.

Comment: I see. Added a couple of preference libraries, so you might consider using them as they allow to bind preferences - this might help with reducing code.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!!! You are a genius! It gives you the possibility to use Colors in layouts and in code as well. Here is a good example to use it in code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17277618/get-color-value-programmatically-when-its-a-reference-theme

Comment: your answer and this code : ?demoColor , help me lot . thats i want .

Answer (score 10):

You can't change an app's resources, they are all constants. Instead you can save your color in SharedPrefences and use the color from there.

See [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values).

If your app already has a R.color.green defined and you just want to access it based on what API returned you use:

```
int resourceID = getResources().getIdentifier("green", "color", getPackageName());
```

Comment: I know about `SharedPreferences` and I think you didn't get me, I meant that you can create a file called `colors.xml` right? and then on it create items with colors with HEX, then I would like to know if I can moddify this value programmatically to first put the demo color and then the real color.

Comment: You can't change contents of colors.xml at runtime, instead you can keep all possible colors in it and use getIdentifier to get the color returned by API. You can keep the chosen color in SharedPref and retrieve it later in next session till API call finishes

Comment: Ya, but how to set the textColor of a textView or button? if I have 10 Textviews and I want to put them on green text I have to put the setText(java) for each and asigning the value from SharedPreferences?...

Comment: Yep, that's the only way. And besides, changing Resources can later lead to all sorts of confusion in your app

Answer (score 3):

store hex color codes into sharedpreferences and then use parsecolor function  store your all hexcodes of colors into  sessions as a string and whenever you want to change color of perticular button ,textview..just retrive that color code from session and use it as
        for ex.
     `session.setString("white","#FFFFFF");
String colorname=session.getString("white");yourtextview.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colorname);`

Comment: What's that? Can you expain a little bit your code?