# Is it possible to reference attributes from styles.xml file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles

I want to give the user the possibility to switch the colors skin of my entire application. I mean to switch the style of some custom views of the app dynamically when the user presses a button of the screen. I know that if you call `Activity.setTheme()` before `onCreate()` method, you can change the theme of the app dynamically, but normal Views (for example, `NavigationView`) with custom styles applied on their xml layout, do not have setTheme or setStyle methods, so it is does not appear possible to change their style dynamically.

I think that my objective would be possible referencing colors declared in an AppTheme declared inside `styles.xml` file. I mean, i can have two AppThemes declared, each one with one set of colors, and then, in the custom styles declared for the custom views, reference the colors. Something like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="customColor">#111111</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AnotherColor" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="customColor">#222222</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBar">
        <!-- title text color -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@styles/customColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

So, by default, the custom Color declared on my "AppTheme" will be applied by default, using color `111111`. But when I change the theme of my app using `setTheme(R.styles.AppTheme_AnotherColor)` the color applied will be `222222`. If this would be possible it would be perfect! but it is not possible or I don't know how to access to a color declared inside a style directly from another style of the same `styles.xml` file. I mean that `@styles/customColor` is not correct and I don't know how to access that color.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Custom attributes are referenced using `?attr/customAttributeName`, so in your case you need to put `?attr/customColor` in your `CustomActionBar` theme.

Comment: @TR4Android does not find the atribute. Test it please. You should reference it from another <style> tag. Something is wrong because can't find it.

Comment: Have you defined it in your `attrs.xml` file? Each custom attribute needs to be defined there so it can be found. Put something like `<resources><attr name="customColor" format="color"/></resources>` in that file.

Comment: @TR4Android And will I have the possibility to change it's value in my AppTheme and AppTheme.AnotherColor dinamically?

Comment: Yes, I've made it work in one of my apps. Themes and styles on Android can be at perky at times though...

Comment: @TR4Android please, how to give value to that customColor inside AppTheme style?

Comment: That code is just fine, use the `customColor` there without any modification.

Comment: @TR4Android I'm not understanding you. How to give value to the customColor inside the AppTheme Style? I can't do it. I tryed with <item name="?attr/customColor">#111111</item> but can't find ?attr

Comment: No, you've already correctly defined your customColor, but not correctly referenced it in your `CustomActionBar` style. That's where you need to put this: `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">?attr/customColor</item>`

Comment: @TR4Android No, you don't understand me. My english is bad. I need to set the value for customColor in my AppTheme style! After that, i will reference it in the other styles. But first i need to set it's value depending on which theme is set in my app. Do you understand me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120987/discussion-between-nullpointerexception-and-tr4android).

Comment: Yes, I do. The value is defined as you've put it in your example code above, no changes need to be made there.

Comment: @TR4Android please accept my chat invitation two messages ago.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to add custom attributes and colors to the themes. For this you need to:

1. Define your custom attribute in your `res/values/attrs.xml` file:

   ```
   <resources>
       <attr name="customColor" format="color" />
   </resources>
   ```
2. Define the attribute's value in your themes:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
       <item name="customColor">#111111</item>
   </style>

   <style name="AppTheme.AnotherColor" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
       <item name="customColor">#222222</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Use your custom attribute in your styles:

   ```
   <style name="CustomActionBar">
       <!-- title text color -->
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">?attr/customColor</item>
   </style>
   ```

Comment: thank you so much. Is it possible to write the value of the custom xml attribute (created in attrs.xml) with java code?

Comment: Not easily. Android themes and styles are really one of the most inflexible things. You can find a few hints [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34178187/5731450).

Comment: TR4Android it is possible to use this with a widget color¿? Widget does not have theme, so can't set the value of the attr setting the theme on the widget... must be other way

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with widgets, but you could try just using something like `android:background="?attr/customColor"`.